# Split functionalities of an application into plugins with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, shared-libraries

Pretty much like the title says, I want to split some parts of my Qt application into plugins, so I
can add new functionalities at runtime. Ideally, plugins would be compiled separately and put into a
dedicated path for plugins; when the application launches, installed extensions are automatically
loaded, or can be reloaded at the user request at any time.

I should mention that the objects I want to put into plugins are not `QObject`s, but if it can make
the solution simpler it's acceptable that they inherit from `QObject`.

How can I do that? I want the simplest solution that's portable and doesn't require anything else
than Qt (no external dependencies).

Comment: Why not just to use [standard Qt plugin system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html)?

Comment: That page says, _[use the high-level API] for writing extensions to Qt itself: custom database drivers, image formats, text codecs, custom styles, etc._ Moreover, it says for the low-level API that '_not only Qt itself but also Qt application can be extended through plugins_', which suggests the high-level API is only for extending Qt itself, not some application. Do you still think the standard Qt plugin system can be used for "regular" application plugins?

Comment: I think yes. I see no reasons why not to use them (I use for same things). Except you need a static linkage of some of Qt plugins.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: then provide an example. You do not need to give one as thorough as I wrote, just something that shows how easier/better it is. Go get your award; I don't want to give it to the one-liner answer.

Comment: I don't care about reputation. Anyway, it is not couple lines of code, you may see an example in Qt documentation. The most complex thing is correct splitting of your logic + deployment stuff. I wrote a comment because I don't want to prepare out-of-box solution, and it takes time. I think that you should try to do it by yourself and ask for help if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

*Although I answer my own question, I'm more than interested to hear others'!*

For a start, you need to have a common interface among your plugins. Here's an example:

```
class MyPlugin
{
public:
    virtual ~MyPlugin() {}  // Needs to be virtual. Important!

    // Put here your method(s)
    virtual void frobnicate() = 0;
};
```

Do not name your interface like this, though. If your plugins represent video codecs, name it
"VideoCodec", for example. Some prefer to put an "I" before interfaces' name (e.g. `IVideoCodec`).
Also, some people would tell you to have public methods calling protected virtuals, but that's not
strictly necessary there.

Why an interface? That's because it's the only way the application can use plugins without knowing
the classes themselves beforehand. This means that because the application doesn't know the
classes, the plugin must allow creating the plugin component via a *factory*. In fact, the only
required function to declare is a factory function that creates a fresh instance of the "plugin".
This factory function could be declared as such:

```
extern "C" std::unique_ptr<MyPlugin> MyPlugin_new();
```

(You need `extern "C"`, otherwise you'll get trouble with `QLibrary` because of C++ name mangling ―
see below)

The factory function need not be without parameters, but the parameters must make sense for all types
of plugins. This could be a hashtable or a file containing general configuration information, or
even better, an interface for a configuration object, for instance.

Now the loading part. The easiest way is to use a `QDirIterator` initialized to the plugin
directory, iterate through all files and try to load them. Something along the lines of...

```
void load_plugins_from_path(const QString &plugin_dir)
{
    QDirIterator it(plugin_dir, QDir::Files, QDir::Readable);

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try_load_plugin(it.next());
    }
}
```

(it's written like it's a function, but it should be a method)

Do not try in any way to filter the files by extension or by using the `QDir::Executable` flag: this
will needlessly reduce the portability of the program―each OSes have their own file extensions, and `QDir::Executable` only work on unices (probably because there's no exec bit on Windows).
Here, the method `load_plugins_from_path` just loads plugins from one given path; the caller may
invoke that method over the elements of a list containing all the paths to search for plugins, for
example. `try_load_plugin` may be defined like this:

```
void try_load_plugin(const QString &filename)
{
    QLibrary lib(filename);

    auto factory = reinterpret_cast<decltype (MyPlugin_new) *>(lib.resolve("MyPlugin_new"));

    if (factory) {
        std::unique_ptr<MyPlugin> plugin(factory());

        // Do something with "plugin", e.g. store in a std::vector
    }
}
```

`decltype` is used on `MyPlugin_new` so we doesn't have to specify its type
(`std::unique_ptr<MyPlugin> (*)()`) and using it with `auto` will save you the trouble of changing
the code more than it needs to be, should you change the signature of `MyPlugin_new`.

This method just tries to load a file as a library (whether it's a valid library file or not!) and
attempts to resolve the required function, returning `nullptr` if either we're not dealing with a
valid library file or the requested symbol (our function) didn't exist. Note that because we do the
search directly in a dynamic library, we must know the exact name of the entity in that library.
Because C++ mangles names, and that mangling is dependent on the implementation, the only sensible
thing is to use `extern "C"` functions. Don't worry though: `extern "C"` will only prevent
overloading of that function, but otherwise all C++ can be used inside of that function. Also, even
though the factory function is not inside any namespace, it won't collide with other factory
functions in other libraries, because we use *explicit linking*; that way, we can have
`MyPlugin_new` from plugin A and `MyPlugin_new` from plugin B, and they will live at separate
addresses.

Finally, if your set of plugins is too diverse to be expressed by one interface, one solution is to
simply define (possibly) multiple factories inside of your plugins, each returning a pointer to a
different kind of interface.

Comment: This is the best way to achieve what you asked. I don't see the point answering your own question after setting up a bounty....

Comment: Well, this is the way I found, and to show that I did my homework, I put it there as an answer rather than in the question, should the answer be the only one. But the process looks convoluted, especially considering that Qt handles so many things in a very high-level way, and that's a bit hard to teach. It might be a big question but I hoped that someone would show up and say, "this is a simpler way to do it". Maybe my attempt to get an answer is too clumsy...

Answer (score 3):

Qt already has a class called [QPluginLoader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html) that does what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @simurg: care to provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: @Jarhmander Check Qt's Echo Plugin Example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-echoplugin-example.html It is quite simple to follow and better than any example code I'll put here